# Spring Batch chunk size is inconsistent in ItemWriter in multi threaded Step

Tags: spring, multithreading, spring-batch

I have a problem in getting the Task Executor and chunk size consistent. Below is my code snippet, where I expect one thread to read 4000 record and then sent to ItemWriter, but while I debugged putting logs, it is shown that each thread having different chunk size which is not consistent. If my chunk size is 4000, one thread processes 4000, other may be 900, other may be 3000. I am using ThreadPoolExecutor as Task Executor.

```
My requirement is to process each chunk in parallel .. 



<batch:step id="loadPayments" next="archiveFileStep">
            <batch:tasklet task-executor="taskLetExecutor">
                <batch:chunk reader="itemReader" writer="itemWriter" commit-interval="4000">
                    <batch:listeners>
                        <batch:listener>
                            <bean class="com.jpmc.cib.p3.batch.integration.samples.payments.PaymentChunkListener"/>
                        </batch:listener>
                    </batch:listeners>
                </batch:chunk>
            </batch:tasklet>
        </batch:step>


ThreadPoolTaskExecutor taskExecutor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
        taskExecutor.setCorePoolSize(20);
        taskExecutor.setMaxPoolSize(100);
        taskExecutor.setQueueCapacity(1000);
```

Also, I made the ItemReader as Synchronised...

```
  @Override
    protected synchronized T doRead() throws Exception {
        return super.doRead();
    }
```

Comment: What reader are you using?